# why isn't my if statement working?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need user input to save to a database and then display on an app.
If the user's input is left blank, I need to display an error message.

I'm running into trouble with the error messages displaying at all.
When user input is blank, a blank post is saved to the db and then displayed with no content rather than displaying the error message.

I am using Python, Jinja2, Flask, HTML

Thanks!!

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

        blog_title = str(request.form['title'])
        blog_body = str(request.form['body'])

        title_error = ''
        body_error = ''

        if len(blog_title) == 0:
            title_error = 'Please give your blog a title'
            return title_error

        if len(blog_body) == 0:
            body_error = "Please give your blog some content"
            return body_error
        else:
            new_blog = Blog(blog_title, blog_body)
            db.session.add(new_blog)
            db.session.commit()

            blog_id = new_blog.id

            return redirect(url_for('blogs', id=blog_id))

    else:
        return render_template('/newpost_form.html')
```

Comment: well you are returning an empty string (`title_error`), no?

Comment: @patrick He redefines the string just before the `return`. However, he really doesnt need to ever define it as `''` at all honestly.

Comment: @pstatix I think you are right, also the first if should be followed by for an "elif", right?

Comment: @patrick that's also true

Comment: @DamianLattenero Do you mean the `if request.method`? No that can go straight to `else`. However, if you were talking about the `if len(blog_title)` followed by `if len(blog_body)`, yes the second `if` should be `elif`. Having two `if` statements mean the program will check them both (theoretically, the `return` poses a unique alternative).

Comment: What does your calling function look like?

Comment: @pstatix 
    `@app.route('/newpost', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def newpost():`
If this is calling function? I'm a very early beginner! :)

Comment: You are returning a value from a called function; that returned value must be stored somehow and somewhere on the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider integrating [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). I only do flask forms that way. Provides a lot of validation tools that make it easy to work with

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtf.fields import StringField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtf.validators import DataRequired

class NewBlogForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired(message='one')])
    body = TextAreaField('Body', validators=[DataRequired(message='two')])
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

**routes.py**

```
from forms import NewBlogForm

@app.route('/newpost', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_post():
    form = NewBlogForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        blog = Blog(form.title.data, form.body.data)
        db.session.add(blog)
        db.session.commit()  # should have try block to catch any errors
        return redirect(url_for('blogs', id=blog.id))
    return render_template('newposts_form.html', form=form)
```

**newposts_form.html**

```
<form>
    <ul>
    {% for error in form.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.title.label }}{{ form.title }}
    {{ form.body.label }}{{ form.body }}
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

If you are using [Flask-Bootstrap](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/) they support `wtf forms` and show errors in a really clean way.

Answer (score 0):

you are reasinging the values of the variables, do the following:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    blog_title = str(request.form['title'])
    blog_body = str(request.form['body'])

    if len(blog_title) == 0:
        return 'Please give your blog a title'
    elif len(blog_body) == 0:
        return "Please give your blog some content"
    else:
        new_blog = Blog(blog_title, blog_body)
        db.session.add(new_blog)
        db.session.commit()

        blog_id = new_blog.id

        return redirect(url_for('blogs', id=blog_id))

else:
    return render_template('/newpost_form.html')
```

Comment: After trying this, I get the error message for the title to display (however, it is on a new page for some reason). I do not get an error message for the body, and it saves the populated title with no body to my database..

Comment: @TJH well, that's another issue, you just can't return a String as my example, I thought you put them as example too... you have to render another templete for each case